# If Powershell command separator is ; (semicolon), why does "date; dir" make dir output extra details?

Tags: command-line, powershell

I understand that semicolon is a command separator in Powershell.  `echo "hello"; dir` gives this output.

```
PS C:\> echo "hello"; dir
hello

Directory: C:\

Mode         LastWriteTime     Length Name
----         -------------     ------ ----
d-----       2018-04-29 13:02         BCD_Backup
d-----       2018-12-02 14:08         Dell
<snip>
```

But why does `date; dir` give this output?

```
PS C:\> date; dir

Friday, December 14, 2018 11:14:23

PSPath            : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\BCD_Backup
PSParentPath      : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\
PSChildName       : BCD_Backup
PSDrive           : C
PSProvider        : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem
PSIsContainer     : True
Name              : BCD_Backup
FullName          : C:\BCD_Backup
Parent            :
Exists            : True
Root              : C:\
Extension         :
CreationTime      : 2018-04-29 13:02:31
CreationTimeUtc   : 2018-04-29 11:02:31
LastAccessTime    : 2018-04-29 13:02:31
LastAccessTimeUtc : 2018-04-29 11:02:31
LastWriteTime     : 2018-04-29 13:02:31
LastWriteTimeUtc  : 2018-04-29 11:02:31
Attributes        : Directory
Mode              : d-----
BaseName          : BCD_Backup
Target            : {}
LinkType          :


PSPath            : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Dell
PSParentPath      : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\
<snip>
```

Comment: Interesting question. I hope it gets answered, because I have no idea myself, and I know my way around powershell.

Comment: also: https://www.vistax64.com/threads/powershell-and-the-semicolon.244649/

Comment: I think this **BUG** is the result of PowerShells **feature** to postpone/defer output to **not** insert the same header for successive commands and seems to exist for quite a long time.

Comment: @LotPings - what's fascinating is that Get-ChildItem doesn't appear to have any options that would generate the output that > date; Get-ChildItem results in.

Comment: Agreed, I'm also curious what is executed with `date` at all. It's not an alias nor a cmdlet or .exe file (same issue in PSv6 BTW)

Comment: Great question. This is not specific to `date`. I get the same unexpected output when trying `ps | select -f 1 ; dir`.

Comment: Implicit `Out-Default` sees input as single object stream. It have no way to know where output of each command ends.

Comment: This might be encoding related. The problem can be prevented by [piping to `more`](https://superuser.com/a/812471/254473): `date; dir | more`.

Comment: This seems to only occur when you use date; 'almost anything esle after'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [`Out-Default` docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/out-default?view=powershell-7#description):

> PowerShell automatically adds `Out-Default` **to the end of every pipeline**…

Definitely, a semicolon itself does not suffice for recognizing such a state:

```
Get-Alias -Name gal; Get-Location
```

> ```
> CommandType     Name                                          Version    Source
> -----------     ----                                          -------    ------
> Alias           gal -> Get-Alias
>
> Drive        : D
> Provider     : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem
> ProviderPath : D:\PShell
> Path         : D:\PShell
> ```

Adding `Out-Default` to the pipeline explicitly solves the problem:

```
Get-Alias -Name gal | Out-Default; Get-Location
```

> ```
> CommandType     Name                                          Version    Source
> -----------     ----                                          -------    ------
> Alias           gal -> Get-Alias
>
>
> Path
> ----
> D:\PShell
> ```

Answer (score 3):

As powershell executes statements one-by-one, I think, it applies output formatting of the first statement to all subsequent statements.

As `Get-Date` returns an object of `DateTime` type, it gets formatted as list, affecting your 'dir' output.

You can test this assumption by changing return type of `Get-Date` to string using 'format' option:

```
date -Format yyyy-MM-dd ; dir
```

(this will produce default output for 'dir')

Or by changing default output formatting by pipelining it to `Format-Table`:

```
 date | Format-Table ; dir
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to only occur when you use date; 'almost anything else after' that including other PS cmdlets (just tried a few).

'date' as typed appears to be calling core Windows (just like cmd.exe) to get that datestring back, PowerShell is trying to do something with that string it appears.

If you reverse this, 'anything here';date, does not exhibit this oddity. It just does this...

```
 dir;date


    Directory: D:\Scripts


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----         9/1/2018   2:12 PM                .vscode
d-----         7/3/2018   4:44 PM                CheckURI

....


DisplayHint : DateTime
Date        : 12/14/2018 12:00:00 AM
Day         : 14
DayOfWeek   : Friday
DayOfYear   : 348
Hour        : 14
Kind        : Local
Millisecond : 516
Minute      : 42
Month       : 12
Second      : 22
Ticks       : 636803953425164049
TimeOfDay   : 14:42:22.5164049
Year        : 2018
DateTime    : Friday, December 14, 2018 2:42:22 PM
```